# Unity - Include git package as a dependency in package.json of an embedded package

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, package.json

I created an embedded unity package and trying to add a git unity package as a dependency.
In this case I'm trying to add SocketIOUnity (https://github.com/itisnajim/SocketIOUnity), but this goes for any other package as well.

I'm trying to add SocketIOUnity to my package.json so that it can be resolved as a dependency.

I tried this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "com.itisnajim.socketiounity": "https://github.com/itisnajim/SocketIOUnity.git"
}
```

And got the following error:

```
[Package Manager Window] Cannot perform upm operation: Unable to add package [https://github.com/my-package.git]:
  Package my-package@https://github.com/my-package.git has invalid dependencies or related test packages:
    com.itisnajim.socketiounity (dependency): Version 'https://github.com/itisnajim/SocketIOUnity.git' is invalid. Expected a 'SemVer' compatible value. [NotFound].
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

It seems git urls are [only supported in the project manifest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-git.html).

I also tried this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "com.itisnajim.socketiounity": "1.1.4"
}
```

And got the following error:

```
[Package Manager Window] Cannot perform upm operation: Unable to add package [https://github.com/my-package.git]:
  Package my-package@https://github.com/my-package.git has invalid dependencies or related test packages:
    com.itisnajim.socketiounity (dependency): Package [com.itisnajim.socketiounity@1.1.4] cannot be found [NotFound].
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

Which makes sense, as I don't believe this package has been pushed to any registry that unity is fetching from.

How am I supposed to do it? Is it even technically supported by Unity?

Comment: What's your Git and Unity versions? I've had problems with this as well

Comment: Unity 2021 LTS, I don't think it's related to version though it's more of a functionality related question

Comment: well, the docs say that you need Git version 2.14.0 at least, so that might be a part of the problem (at least for some people) but the issue exists with up-to-date versions for me too

Comment: Hmm I don't think you entirely understand the issue

Comment: Have you got the answer? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unity allows you to add Git packages as dependencies in the Project Manifest file, but not in the package.json file of an embedded package. **You need to add it to the project manifest file.**

**Add this line to dependencies in manifest.json:**

```
"com.itisnajim.socketiounity": "https://github.com/itisnajim/SocketIOUnity.git"
```

**Example:**

```json
    {
      "name": "com.name.package",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "displayName": "package",
      "description": "description",
      "dependencies": {
        "com.itisnajim.socketiounity": "https://github.com/itisnajim/SocketIOUnity.git"
      }
    }
```

**Source:**

https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/upm-dependencies.svg

Comment: Yeah that I know, but will people who install my custom dependency have it installed? Isn't there a single manifest file for all the project packages rather than per package?

Comment: It isn't per package? If you add the dependency to your project manifest file, anyone who installs your custom package will also have the dependency installed automatically. **The project manifest file serves as a central location for managing dependencies for the entire Unity project, also including all the packages within it.** So when someone installs your package, **Unity will check the project manifest file for any dependencies and install them.**

Comment: From what I understand, Unity is pretty weird and want you to specify git dependencies in manifest.json. **package.json is for metadata, name, etc and manifest.json is for dependencies.** When you publish your package to the Unity Package Manager registry **with the manifest.json file that includes the Git dependencies, other people who import your package will also have those dependencies installed in their projects.** If you have any more questions, tell me.

Comment: If the project manifest file  serves as a central location for managing dependencies for the entire Unity project, I don't see and you how a package can also have its own manifest.json, and unity will resolve its dependencies when installing your package? And if it can't, how can users installing your package be affected by it?

Comment: Have you successfully managed to include git dependencies in a custom package you created and have them resolved upon package installation?

Comment: I did! Using the method in my answer, and looking at Unity Documentation, it is how you need to do it.

Comment: Can you please address the message before that? Not sure how it makes sense if there's only 1 manifest file per project and not per package.

Comment: When a user installs a package **that has its own manifest.json file**. Unity will resolve the dependencies for that package based on the information in the manifest file and install any missing dependencies. A package's manifest.json file specifies the dependencies required by the package and are installed at **project level, rather than being limited to the package itself.** **TLDR, I wasn't clear enough but I meant the package's manifest.json AND NOT the project's manifest.json.** Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Just tried adding a manifest.json inside the package itself and unity seems to ignore it when installing the package. Do you by any chance have a working exmaple?

Comment: There's already one in my answer. For "com" packages, you would have to format it like ```"com.name.package": "ver.x.x"```. Could you paste your manifest.json here? I can check for issues.

Comment: This is the manifest.json in my package:
{
  "dependencies": {
 "com.itisnajim.socketiounity": "https://github.com/itisnajim/SocketIOUnity.git"
  }
}

Comment: Your full example seems to be a package.json, I don't think manifest.json has these fields, and package.json doesn't support git dependencies of course.

Comment: No, it's a manifest.json. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-manifestPkg.html

Comment: Just tried it exactly as your example, getting the following error:
Asset Packages/mypackage/manifest.json has no meta file, but it's in an immutable folder. The asset will be ignored.

Comment: You linked to package manifest which talks about package.json

Comment: Sorry about that. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-manifestPrj.html

Comment: Yeah, if you'll read it you'll see that it doesn't support the fields you mentioned. Plus it can't really be inside a package (see my error above).

Comment: Yeah, if you read it correctly, you might come across this in the example: ```"com.unity.my-git-package": "https://my.repository/my-package.git#v1.2.3"```

Comment: You're missing the point :) A manifest.json can contain a git package, but you can't have a manifest.json inside a custom package.

Comment: Sorry about that, if I can't help you, please check the official documentation as it looks like it changed/is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this post, You **cannot** add git dependencies to the `package.json` file in your UPM packages.

It says so here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-git.html.

I recommend updating the installation instructions for your package(s) to explicitly state what dependencies users will need to download and how.